# Aggregation and crosstabulation of observations of animal individuals

Tags: r, aggregate, crosstab

I am doing a basic aggregation of 30 years of observations of animal individuals, and I have a rawdata file where there is one line per animal individual observation, where individual name and time of observation are parameters.

This script gives a long table format, and I need a long format:

```
table(dis2$who, lubridate::year(dis2$tid))
```

Here's the data:

```
> dput(dis2)
structure(list(who = c("KA-3", "KA-4", "KA-4", "KA-5", "KA-6", 
"KA-6", "KA-7", "KA-7", "KA-8", "KA-8", "KA-12", "KA-12", "KA-12", 
"KB-4", "KB-4", "KB-4", "KB-4", "KB-4", "KB-4", "KB-4", "KB-6", 
"KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", 
"KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-6", "KB-7", "KB-7", "KB-7", 
"KB-7", "KB-11", "KB-11", "KB-11", "KB-11", "KB-11", "KB-11", 
"KB-11", "KB-11", "KB-11", "KB-11", "KB-11", "KB-11", "KC-1", 
"KC-1", "KC-1", "KC-3", "KC-3", "KE-1", "KE-1", "KE-1", "KE-1", 
"KE-1", "KE-1", "KE-3", "KF-1", "KF-1", "KF-1", "KF-1", "KF-1", 
"KG-6", "KG-6", "KG-6", "KH-2", "KH-2", "KH-2", "KH-3", "KH-3", 
"KH-4", "KH-4", "KH-5", "KH-5", "KH-6", "KH-6", "KH-7", "KH-7", 
"KH-7", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", 
"KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1", "KI-1"
), film = c(14, 10, 14, 18, 10, 18, 14, 14, 10, 14, 15, 18, 19, 
20, 30, 37, 47, 48, 48, 49, 23, 23, 30, 32, 35, 38, 41, 43, 47, 
48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 36, 37, 43, 49, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 39, 
42, 43, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 998, 50, 50, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 
74, 74, 8, 8, 8, 8, 52, 88, 90, 91, 84, 84, 92, 92, 93, 92, 104, 
92, 93, 84, 93, 93, 93, 94, 999, 999, 95, 95, 96, 96, 97, 97, 
97, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 102), frame = c(36, 15, 34, 16, 18, 15, 
35, 37, 13, 35, 27, 18, 14, 17, 24, 17, 11, 22, 24, 34, 29, 31, 
25, 15, 18, 12, 5, 23, 19, 9, 10, 14, 16, 17, 37, 15, 8, 14, 
29, 33, 35, 37, 18, 22, 22, 33, 10, 8, 21, 36, 30, 8, 1, 2, 3, 
2, 19, 36, 3, 5, 21, 8, 4, 8, 11, 14, 2, 19, 16, 16, 24, 26, 
6, 21, 19, 27, 8, 30, 26, 25, 30, 20, 33, 19, 1, 2, 1, 24, 19, 
22, 15, 17, 19, 5, 9, 27, 1, 8, 1), tid = structure(c(570067200, 
570067200, 570067200, 570412800, 570067200, 570412800, 570067200, 
570067200, 570067200, 570067200, 570067200, 570412800, 570412800, 
633744000, 634435200, 634608000, 635126400, 635126400, 635126400, 
635126400, 633744000, 633744000, 634435200, 634435200, 634521600, 
634694400, 635040000, 635040000, 635126400, 635126400, 635126400, 
635126400, 635126400, 635126400, 634608000, 634608000, 635040000, 
635126400, 634608000, 634608000, 634608000, 634608000, 634608000, 
634694400, 635040000, 635040000, 635040000, 635126400, 635126400, 
635126400, 640483200, 640483200, 640483200, 640483200, 640483200, 
659664000, 659664000, 659664000, 659664000, 659664000, 659664000, 
659664000, 569721600, 569721600, 569721600, 569721600, 656035200, 
668476800, 668476800, 668476800, 668476800, 668476800, 668476800, 
668476800, 668476800, 668476800, 668736000, 668476800, 668476800, 
668476800, 668476800, 668476800, 668476800, 668476800, 575424000, 
655948800, 668563200, 668563200, 668563200, 668563200, 668563200, 
668563200, 668563200, 668563200, 668563200, 668563200, 668563200, 
668563200, 668649600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-99L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just use `table`?

```r
table(df3$who, lubridate::year(df3$tid))
#>       
#>        1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996
#>   NP-3    0    9    3    4    4    1
#>   NQ-1    0   17    0    0    0    0
#>   NQ-2    0    5    1    0    0    0
#>   NQ-5    0    2    0    0    0    0
#>   NR-3    0    3    0    0    0    0
#>   NT-1    0    1    2    3    0    0
#>   NT-6    0    2    0    0    0    0
#>   NU-1    0   16    0    0    0    0
#>   NU-2    0    6    0    0    0    0
#>   NU-3    0   11    6    0    0    0
#>   NU-5    0   17    0    0    0    0
#>   NU-6    3   14    8    0    0    0
#>   NU-9    0    4    0    0    0    0
```

**EDIT**

Update with the revised data:

```
table(dis2$who, lubridate::year(dis2$tid))
#>        
#>         1988 1990 1991
#>   KA-12    3    0    0
#>   KA-3     1    0    0
#>   KA-4     2    0    0
#>   KA-5     1    0    0
#>   KA-6     2    0    0
#>   KA-7     2    0    0
#>   KA-8     2    0    0
#>   KB-11    0   12    0
#>   KB-4     0    7    0
#>   KB-6     0   14    0
#>   KB-7     0    4    0
#>   KC-1     0    3    0
#>   KC-3     0    2    0
#>   KE-1     0    6    0
#>   KE-3     0    1    0
#>   KF-1     4    1    0
#>   KG-6     0    0    3
#>   KH-2     0    0    3
#>   KH-3     0    0    2
#>   KH-4     0    0    2
#>   KH-5     0    0    2
#>   KH-6     0    0    2
#>   KH-7     0    0    3
#>   KI-1     1    1   13
```

Comment: When running the table format script above I don't get the wide format table as you show in your answer, but I get the 'who' in the first column, then the 'year' in the second column, and 'Freq' in the last column.

Comment: @Dag the above is just the result of taking your exact data frame and running the exact above code.  Have you tried that in a fresh R session?

Comment: @Dag I've updated the answer with your new data and it's in the same format you showed initially as the requested output. Are you getting something different, or are you getting the same but want something different?

Comment: I am getting the right format now. Don't know what happened earlier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We could do a `group_by` the 'year' and 'who' and `summarise` with the `sum` of 'frame', then reshape into 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df3 %>% 
    group_by(who, year = year(tid)) %>%
    summarise(frame = sum(frame)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = frame)
```

If we just need the frequency

```
df3 %>%
     count(who, year = year(tid)) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 13 x 7
#   who   `1992` `1993` `1994` `1995` `1996` `1991`
#   <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 NP-3       9      3      4      4      1      0
# 2 NQ-1      17      0      0      0      0      0
# 3 NQ-2       5      1      0      0      0      0
# 4 NQ-5       2      0      0      0      0      0
# 5 NR-3       3      0      0      0      0      0
# 6 NT-1       1      2      3      0      0      0
# 7 NT-6       2      0      0      0      0      0
# 8 NU-1      16      0      0      0      0      0
# 9 NU-2       6      0      0      0      0      0
#10 NU-3      11      6      0      0      0      0
#11 NU-5      17      0      0      0      0      0
#12 NU-6      14      8      0      0      0      3
#13 NU-9       4      0      0      0      0      0
```